# WebdriverIO Custom Reporter - TypeError: Cannot read property 'write'/'complete' of undefined

Tags: javascript, report, webstorm, webdriver-io

I am implementing a custom reporter in WebdriverIO.  Following a tutorial (https://webdriver.io/docs/customreporter.html), I have written the following code:

```
let Reporter = require ('@wdio/reporter').default;
Reporter.reporterName = 'HTMLReporter';

module.exports = class HTMLReporter extends Reporter {
    constructor (options) {
        options = Object.assign(options, { stdout: true });
        super(options);
    }

    onTestPass (test) {
        this.write(`Congratulations! Your test "${test.title}" passed!`);
    }
};
```

When running this code, however, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined`.  There seems to be an issue with `write` command in the line `this.write('Congratulations! Your test "${test.title}" passed!');`.

I am able to bypass this error by changing `this.write('Congratulations! Your test "${test.title}" passed!');` to `console.log('Congratulations! Your test "${test.title}" passed!');`, however when I run this code, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined`.  Why am I getting these errors?  How can I fix my code to make it run correctly?

Comment: I am facing the same exactly error, any progress on it?

Answer (score 0):

since i am facing the same problem, I have decided to replace:

```
this.write();
```

with:

```
fs.writeFileSync();
```

and it worked as expected

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, where did you declare FS?

Comment: in the reporter class where you extend the wdio reporter